# the access token removed while getting the user info from facebook

Tags: android, facebook

as new to the android and facebook sdk but tried some of the thing with facebook like login and getting info in my app so upto what i did is i used some lib which is linked with facebook sdk and through which i m login and getting the info here is the link for that lib [facebook lib](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook)

until now while i m login and getting the info is going good but problem came when other user login and tried to get the info from his profile the email is coming null and check the log its shows

SessionStatusCallback: state=OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED, session={Session state:OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[photo_upload, publish_stream, video_upload, share_item, user_friends, email, installed, friends_about_me, status_update, create_note, basic_info, publish_actions]},

ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions is there in that log so in my case login with work prefectly but when my friend login and getting info something went wrong and email is coming as null as mention above .So,please can anyone suggest me what is wrong i m doing.Thanks for any reply.